# Don't display object's data if property doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to choose not to display an object's data if a property is missing from the object. I'm calling data from a REST API that removes a `price_1` property from an object if the item is no longer available for purchase. I've done a little bit of research into `delete` but from my understanding that's only for deleting a reference to a property, not an object. I'm not sure if it's possible to entirely remove an object if a property doesn't exist, but this would be the ideal solution. I also want to know if the solution would be better suited as a custom filter.

I've tried the following:

```
angular.module('foldsApp.productModule', [])
    .controller('ProductsController', ['$scope', '$log', 'APIService', function ($scope, $log, APIService) {
        $scope.products = {};

        APIService.getData()
            .success(function(res) {
                $scope.products = res.results;
                for (price in $scope.products) {
                    if($scope.products[price].price_1 === 'undefined') {
                        // remove object?
                    }
                }
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $log.log('error: ' + data);
            });

    }]);
```

Right now, the `if($scope.products[price].price_1 === 'undefined')` equates to `false`. I'm not entirely sure why this is happening, but I assume it's because `price_1` does exist on most objects in `$scope.products` and I'm not sure how to work with that. This is my first foray into "higher" level JavaScript, so a few things are going over my head. Any helpful resources are greatly appreciated, thanks.

HTML if that matters:

```
<ul>
    <li dir-paginate="product in products | itemsPerPage: 30">
        <a href="{{ product.link_1 }}"><img src="{{ product.category_product_image_placeholder_image }}" /></a>
        <br>
        {{ product.product_name_text }}
        <br>
        <strong>{{ product.price_1 | currency }}</strong>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can use `ng-if` in markup if that helps, or use `Array.prototype.filter()` to filter data in ajax response

Comment: @charlieftl Oh, cool. Works perfectly. It breaks my grid, but I think that's enough to work with. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

to check for undefined specifically you should use `typeof variable === 'undefined'`:

so:

```
if(typeof $scope.products[price].price_1 === 'undefined'){
    delete $scope.products[price];
}
```

delete will remove properties of an object (which is what it looks like you have) and if they are not referenced anywhere else the garbage collector will pick them up.

Comment: if `$scope.products` is array , delete is not a good practice since it doesn't remove element from array

Comment: true, in that case you can use splice to remove items, however based on the syntax he has i would guess he is iterating over a series of properties on an object.

Comment: yup, just throwing that in...or filter() for array